# Right time to start SEO of brand new site?

Tags: seo

I just developed a website and the age of my site is one day. It's an entertainment related site. I have very good profiles on the rottentomatoes forum, Imdb board, tv.com forum, reddit, voat.co, blu ray forum and also in other good DA (Domain Authority) sites. Now I want to know if I can submit links of my site in related topics in these sites or if I have to wait for some time (one-two months) to start SEO of my site.

A few of my friends told me to wait for one month and few told me to start SEO of my site now. That's why I am confused. Hope you guys will give me the right advice.

Comment: We get question like this periodically. Performance takes a while to determine. Any site that is new has not been properly evaluated. It takes months for a new site to soak into the SERPs properly. It is wise not to make too many changes on new sites except for the obvious and just let it ride out so that solid decisions can be made based upon accurate metrics. Be careful of online SEO assessment sites. They are often inaccurate. Sign up for Google and Bing web master tools for proper metrics that are truly actionable.

Comment: It appears that you're asking when you should start adding links to your site in topics for the purpose of creating _backlinks_? Many forums, like this site, automatically add `nofollow` to links added to posts, so as far as search engines are concerned, those will not benefit you. In fact, it can be viewed as _spammy_ by search engines and end up hurting your site. I'd recommend checking their policies first about self-promotion, like ours [here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) to avoid getting banned.

Comment: @dan I have checked all those sites provide do follow links and i have already their policies. Will links from these sites help me or will count as spam??

Comment: @Spez, most of all links are nofollow and imdb forum board, is blocked by their robots,txt, so Googlebot never encounter, there are some links to crawl and voat.co is newbie social media site, I don't think you should start building links on that, may be Google don't count those links, because it already spammed by many others, and building links on that type of site, is bad for SEO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not really a waiting period on SEO. You really need to plan for SEO on day 0. If your site isn't built in a way or on a platform that has good SEO features, you're going to be suffering trying to implement them later.

Also, SEO is way more than just link-building. You need to make sure that it's appropriately advertised, that it's full of good content and so on. If you want more traffic, then make your site friendlier to traffic. Simple as that. Write good, interesting, properly edited content like there's no tomorrow. Crush your load times as hard as you can. Make sure your theme is fluid and smoothly reflowable, and that it isn't device specific. Make sure you are using valid html, alt tags, rich data, etc, etc...

Answer (score 0):

What I will suggest you, you are already late and you should have to invest in SEO at design development phase. SEO is not all about making links, from choosing domain name to URL structure, a SEO professional can help you in better way. So start investing in SEO and start with ON-Page SEO